# The .get() function for arrays not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
var a = array.get(0);
```

This does not work in jQuery script and I get an error as `array.get is not a function`.

Answer (score 0):

`.get()` is a method on a jQuery object, not a method on an array object.

```
// create jQuery object that contains references to all menus
var menus = $(".menu");

// get a regular array of DOM elements out of that jQuery object
var menuArray = menus.get();

// iterate that regular array
menuArray.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

Here's the [doc for jQuery's `.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/).

---

If you already have an array, then you  just use array syntax to access array elements:

```
var x = [1,2,3];

console.log(x[0]);   // 1
```

Comment: OP: The solution is to follow pretty much every manual on how to access arrays in javascript. `array[0]`. Don't use jQuery unless you need to - it's a layer put on TOP of javascript and will always have worse performance than native javascript. jQuery is not a language - it's a library.

Comment: @h2ooooooo - This should be a comment to the OP's question, not a comment to my answer.

Comment: Technically, you could wrap an array in jQuery and use `get`: `$([2,1,0]).get(0) === 2`, but as @h2ooooooo mentions, that'd be silly.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I disagree. This is an addition to your answer as OP obviously wanted to know how to access an array, hence the answer now includes the info for OP on how to fix the issue.